# function of enumeration-type returns error "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

I have declared a enumeration in a Header-File named including.h like so:

```
#include <xxx>
#iclude "tools.h"

enum Return_Main_Menu { Start, Credits, Help };
```

In addition I have tools.cpp:

```
#include "tools.h"
Return_main_menu mainmenu()
{
  // ...
}
```

a tools.h:

```
#include "including.h"
#include "tools.h"

Return_main_menu mainmenue();
```

and of course a main.cpp with the function call of Return_Main_Menu mainmenu():

```
#include "including.h"

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
cout << "Start\n" << endl;
Return_main_menu mainm = mainmenu();

return 0;
}
```

I don't see any problem, but the compiler returns the error:

```
../xyy/main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
../xyy/main.cpp:9:46: error: 'mainmenu' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: You need to put the function declaration in the `tools.h` header file `Return_main_menu mainmenu();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called the function

```
Return_main_menu hauptmenue();
```

in the .h file and

```
Return_main_menu mainmenu()
```

in the .cpp file and your enumeration is declared as

```
enum Return_Main_Menu { Start, Credits, Help };
```

so you mixed up some names. Keep in mind C++ is case sensitive so Return_Main_Menu is not the same as Return_main_menu.

Comment: No, this was not the solution, I'm sorry. This is just a simple typing mistake, when copying to StackOverFlow
I will change the question.

Comment: So you do have 2 different methods (hauptmenue() and mainmenu()) ? I assumed you named them wrong so the declaration and definition of your function do not fit together.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward declare `mainmenu()` for your `main.cpp` file.  You foward declare `hauptmenue()` in `tool.h`, but that's not included in your `main.cpp` and *is* recursively included in `tools.h`!

Comment: It is, i missed to add to the including.h
I will change the question.